# background drawable for using layer-list not wrapping the parent screen

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen, layer-list

I am trying to re-create a splash screen to conform to Google standard. I tried creating a background drawable for my splash screen which I'll be setting in theme itself. But I am looking for a way to make the bitmap match the parent.

Below is my drawable code: splash_screen_bg.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
 <item android:gravity="center">
 <bitmap android:src="@drawable/logo_show" android:gravity="center" />
 </item>
 </layer-list>
```

Here is code where I am setting this drawable as background of an activity:

```
 <style name="SpTheme" parent="SearchActivityTheme.NoActionBar"> 
 <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorAccentXDark</item>
 <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item> 
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_bg</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't scale image in bitmap. It isn't `ImageView` so it hasn't `scaleType` attribute. Your image will scale depending on folder you put it (drawable-xdpi,drawable-nodpi,...). You just can set backround fill color to what you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

<item
    android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<item android:gravity="center">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/logo_show" android:gravity="center" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thank you, This solved my problem. I had to designed images for various screen sizes and place them in their respective folders (drawable-xdpi,drawable-nodpi,...)